# parse-php-sdk geoPoint withinPolygon exception

Tags: php, parse-platform, geopoints

I'm trying to find locations in a MongoDB within the contiguous United States. To do this, I'm using the query "withinPolygon" and a rectangle around the US. Not exact, but should work :) The response I'm getting is 'bad constraint: $geoWithin' (code 107)

Curious if anyone else has used the "withinPolygon" query and if there's something I'm doing wrong?

Here's the basic code:

```
$query = new Parse\ParseQuery( "Church" );
$nwCornerContiguous = new Parse\ParseGeoPoint( $top, $left );
$neCornerContiguous = new Parse\ParseGeoPoint( $top, $right );
$swCornerContiguous = new Parse\ParseGeoPoint( $bottom, $left );
$seCornerContiguous = new Parse\ParseGeoPoint( $bottom, $right );
$query->withinPolygon( "locationGeopoint",
array( $nwCornerContiguous, $neCornerContiguous, $swCornerContiguous, 
$seCornerContiguous ) );
$results = $query->find();
```

- PHP Version: 5.5.38
- Parse PHP SDK Version: 1.4
- Parse Server Version: 2.3.3-2

Comment: Okay - it turns out the "withinPolygon" feature was added in Parse Server version 2.5

Answer (score 0):

The "withinPolygon" feature was added to Parse Server version 2.5